# Google Earth Engine export buffer as a vector

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a feature collection which has some coordinate points and I apply it buffer function to get a couple of pixels instead of just one.

```
var trf = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/test-earth-12-1/assets/trf_file");
var trf_feature = trf.geometry().buffer(10)
```

Then I get the pixel values like below:

```
  var sampled_points_VV = base_map_VV.sampleRegions({
  collection: trf_feature,
  scale: 10,
  geometries: true
});
```

As last, I export the values.

```
Export.table.toDrive(sampled_points_VV,
"trf", //my task
"GEE_Folder", //my export folder
"trf",  //filer name
"CSV");
```

it returns something like that:

```
0_0,-8.147478230364689,"{""geodesic"":false,""type"":""Point"",""coordinates"":[38.626434323034275,36.82917493409635]}" //row 1

0_1,-8.147478230364689,"{""geodesic"":false,""type"":""Point"",""coordinates"":[38.62652415456269,36.82917493409635]}" //row 2

0_2,-7.195260493027744,"{""geodesic"":false,""type"":""Point"",""coordinates"":[38.626434323034275,36.82926476562476]}" // row 3
```

As it is seen, they belong to the same buffer because coordinate points are so close to each other. However, they are dumped in the same line and there is no unique key for each buffer point. Is there any way to distinguish which points belong to which buffer? Maybe value vector would be great for each buffer, or an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shared your `projects/test-earth-12-1/assets/trf_file` asset, so I cannot tell, but I assume you have a property on each feature that you want to include with each sample?

When you do `trf.geometry().buffer(10)`, you get an `ee.Geometry`, and you lose all your properties. Perhaps you could to buffer each individual feature instead?

```
var trf_feature = trf.map(function (feature) {
  return ee.Feature(
    feature.geometry().buffer(10), 
    feature.toDictionary()
  )
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ee0131d7efb6a716f51b554305418b8d

Comment: Thanks for your answer, excatly it is what I want. I tried to add a dynamic id to each point  but it always return 3. [Here the code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1278faecd3440ae4cf021c5de53f9a47)